# Sorting by count total in AWS CloudWatch Log Insights when aggregating two fields

Tags: aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to create an AWS CloudWatch Log Insights query that will give me the top 5 classes logging error messages from a Java log file.  The query below is able to parse my log file format, and provide a count of errors by className.

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| parse @message '* * * [*][*:*] *' as date, time, logLevel, threadName, className, codeLineNumber, logMessage
| filter logLevel == "ERROR"
| stats count(*) by @logStream, className as errorsByClassName
| sort errorsByClassName desc
| limit 5
```

However, sorting is not working as expected.

Expected outout:

```
@logStream   || className      || errorsByClassName
server2      || MyClass1       || 1000
server4      || MyOtherClass   || 500
server1      || ARandomClass   || 20
```

Actual outout:

```
@logStream   || errorsByClassName || count(*)
server4      || MyOtherClass      || 500
server2      || MyClass1          || 1000
server1      || ARandomClass      || 20
```

It seems like the `as` keyword is being applied to the `className` field and not to the `count(*)`.  Modifying the query to only aggregate by a single field **does** produce the expected results.

How can I set an alias for count when aggregating two fields in order to sort the results?

Thanks!